# How to check if a user was logged on for more days?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to list users who have been logged on for more days on Linux with `last`. I'm not really sure how can I check users logged in for more days.

Comment: Not an answer, but sometimes useful is simple `w`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do `last -F`, you could also try `last -p YYYYMMDDhhmmss` if you want to check a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that

Firstly write a file, output of last command

> last -F >> last.txt

Then get users with login count number

> awk 'NR>1 { a[$1]++ } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] | "sort -nk 2"
>   }' last.txt

```
**Output**
username1 23
username2 35
etc..
```